# Sum of dynamic range

Tags: vba

To begin with - I can't do that using functions because it is part of a script. Given dummy data of

```
28
53
32
24
29
25
93
80
20
```

My formula in Excel is `=SUM($A$2:A2)/SUM($A$2:$A$10)`

I tried to recreate it in VBA and I am stuck at the part of first parenthesis. Rest I think is fine

```
Sub testCumulPerc()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim constSum As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
 
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    firstRow = Range("A2").Row
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    constSum = Range("A2").Value
    
    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 2)
            
       rng.Value = Application.Sum(constSum, ws.Cells(i, 1)) / Application.Sum(Range(Cells(firstRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

It just sums me the 2 given values in first parenthesis, not the range. Also when it comes to the first iteration, it sums A2 with A2 and gives 56 which is not good. The only good calculated percentage is A3 row

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Just use something like so `sum(range("a2").resize(i-firstrow,1)`

Comment: You have got an answer, which you have accepted. Yet, by the comment below the answer I suspect that it was not the answer you hoped for, was it? Or, perhaps you did not ask the right question, or present the problem accurately enough. Please edit your question, *or if the edit would invalidate the given answer*, ask a new question.

Comment: Well, I got my answer I wanted however then the extension pop up in my head and I though that asking it here would be more feasible that creating new thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resize the start range by the number of itterations of the loop.  Using `Resize`

Like so

```
sum(range("a2").resize(i-firstrow,1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me greatly in the first place, however this code is really static. If for example I don't know which column is going to be this data, can I get something like `Range(Cells(2, Xcolumn), Cells(2, Xcolumn).resize(i - firstrow, Xcolumn)` where `Xcolumn` is desired column, set in a variable which has been found to be accurate data? Tried something like this but again it calculates inaccurately